# Unable to ping while nslookup works

Tags: networking, ssh, dns, ssl

I know this question has already been discussed several times.

But my case is quite different than others.

Context :

- PC : Windows 11, running shell commands with "Git Bash"
- Hostinger VPS (Virtual Private Server) running under CentOS 7.
  The VPS is running a backend nodejs express server (mysql) on port XXX.
  Let's say server name is "my.server.fr", IP : AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD (not relevant)

After VPS creation, everything was working well :
Connections with Git Bash through "ssh username@my.server.fr" work fine.

Recently, I needed to secure this backend api server. So I've created and installed a SSL certificate (free of charge because of test modality) using HTTPCS website.

Unfortunately after several tries, not only was I unable to make all of this working, but now I cannot access through ssh username@my.server.fr anymore;
I can only connect using IP address.
ssh username@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd works fine.

But :

- nslookup aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd return my.server.fr
- ping my.server.fr : unknow host
- ssh username@my.server.fr : unknown host
  Made connect tests on other PC and networks (friends), and got same issues.
- Tried to reinit PC, DNS : nothing worked.
- Tried to undo everything regarding SSL but it doesn't made any positive change.

---

UPDATE 1

Forget all about SSL, I'm now aware this is not my issue.

To be more specific, I'm using Hostinger to host my web app, that gives me one first IP Address (xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt), and a domain : mydomain.fr

I'm also using Hostinger to get on VPS that gives me one second IP Address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd (this is the one I got issue) very different from xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt.

I give my VPS a mydomain.fr subdomain name : backend.mydomain.fr

It may be an error to do that (opened question).

And now, I'm confused with A, AAA, CNAME and so one registrations.

Comment: "unknown host" means the normal DNS A (or AAAA) address record lookup failed. That is, when you have a name and ask for its IP address. You gave an example of nslookup working for the *inverse* lookup (the PTR record; when you have the IP address but you ask for the name). It's possible to have a correct PTR record but a bad or missing A or AAAA record, so it's possible for inverse-DNS lookups to succeed while normal DNS lookups fail. Can you confirm that an nslookup for my.server.fr returns aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd?

Comment: @Spiff Just try "nslookup my.server.fr" command -> returns (french error :-)) + Non existent domain. I'll check DNS A (or AAAA) in my Hostinger DNS and let you know. But I think my issue is connected with SSL statement

Comment: Based on your symptoms, I am very sure SSL is not involved at all and this is only DNS issue. Did you forget to renew your domain "my.server.fr"? Check with the registrator. What are DNS servers of your domain — managed by your registrator, your hoster, or those are your custom servers? Check those too.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov  With your help, I can say that SSL is not concerned. I'm just now fighting with my hoster DNS records to make all this work. I just have to upgrade my question to be more specific with that issue. Let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: What is the result of `nslookup my.server.fr`?

Comment: It's ok now !
NikitaKipriyanov and Spiff help me to resolve my issue
One "A line" was missing in my DNS configuration. After adding it, everything work fine now !!!
Thanks to all

Comment: Please do not [add answers to questions](https://superuser.com/posts/1756037/revisions). What you did by [posting an actual answer](https://superuser.com/a/1756126/167207) is 100% fine and how it should be done. Also, no need for end of text signatures or requests for people to help you; just post the question and that is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

I've added one "A line" in my DNS configuration like

```
Type = A
Name = backend
Point to = aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

Everything work fine now : nslookup, ping, ssh...